# Optional properties when deserializing a DataContract/Serializable mish-mash

Tags: c#, serialization, netdatacontractserializer

I have an existing codebase that persists a couple of simple classes to disk via `NetDataContractSerializer`, but the classes are unfortunately not adorned with `[DataContract]`, but rather with `[Serializable]`. This works fine, but now I want to add a few new properties to the persisted classes, while still be able to read the files generated by the old version.

Let's say this is the class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Persisted
{
    public int OldProperty {get;set;}
    public int NewProperty {get;set;}
}
```

Now, when I deserialize the old files, I get an exception because they don't contain `NewProperty`. This makes sense. So I wanted to have `NewProperty` ignored, but while there's a `[OptionalField]` attribute to have the serializer ignore the missing field, it can't be applied to properties - only fields.

So I figured I'll use `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]`, which also has an `IsRequired` property, but this changes the layout of the serialized file, and it can't read the old data files. Moreover, you can't mix `[Serializable]` and `[DataMember]` - if the serializer sees the `[Serializable]` attribute, it ignores the `[DataMember]` directives.

So, barring the option to do a one-time conversion of the old files (possible, but not my first choice), is there a way to get the NetDataContractSerializer to ignore a field in an existing XML serialized object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that when using the `Serializable` attribute, what gets serialized are **fields**, not properties. Since you're using auto-properties, the fields are hidden and you can't add attributes to them.

The solution is simple - don't use auto-properties.